# Trace involving a logarithm of a Klein-Gordon operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform, trace

Calculating effective potentials in QFT one ussually finds traces like

$$\text{Tr}\ln(\Box+m^2)$$

Peskin (page 374) argues that the trace of the operator is the sum over its eigenvalues

$$\text{Tr}\ln(\Box+m^2)=\sum_k \ln(-k^2+m^2)=\int d^4x\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\ln(-k^2+m^2). \tag{11.71}$$

Where the sum over $k$ is replaced by an integral (since k is continuous).

This seems not very clear to me so I tried a different approach by writing
$$\text{Tr}\ln(\Box+m^2)=\int d^4x \langle x|\ln(\Box+m^2)|x\rangle$$
Inserting $\int d^4k|k\rangle \langle k|=1$ one can in principle express it in momentum space
$$\text{Tr}\ln(\Box+m^2)=\int d^4x \int d^4k \int d^4k'  \langle x|k\rangle \langle k|\ln(\Box+m^2)|k'\rangle \langle k'|x\rangle$$ But I'm stuck trying to express the Logarithm on momentum space.

Can anybody give me a clue about it, or another simpler method to evaluate the trace?

Comment: You need $\Box |k'\rangle = - k'^2 | k' \rangle$.

Comment: The trace of the log of an operator is the sum over the log of its eigenvalues because $\textrm{Tr}\ln(\cdot)=\ln\det(\cdot)$ in general and the determinant of an operator is the product of its eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3):

All the authors have done is express the differential operator in momentum space: The D'Alembertian becomes $-k^2$. The trace and log are clearly not basis dependent. You wrote
$$
\langle k|\log (\square+m^2) |k\rangle.
$$
This is all there is to it. The momentum matrix element of the Klein Gordon differential operator is simply
$$
\log(-k^2 + m^2 )
$$
because $\partial_\mu$ is diagonal in momentum space and its Fourier transform is $ik_\mu$ and, similarly, $\partial_\mu^2$ has FT $(ik)^2=-k^2$. Here I've asserted momentum conservation by using a single momentum variable, $k$ (instead of $k$ and $k'$).

Comment: It might be worth including separate $k$ and $k'$ variables and resulting $(2\pi)^4\delta^4(k-k')$ such that the later integral over $k'$ makes sense